# When the stall is actually going to happen?

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu-pipelines

Suppose in a 5 stage pipeline when the stall will actually happen if there is a RAW hazard? The stall will start after Instruction Fetch(IF) stage or Instruction decode(ID) stage? In few cases I see that the stall start after IF that is before executing ID and in multicycle pipeline, the stall starts after decode stage (ID). Can someone please clarify it?

Answer (score 0):

As part of the instruction decode phase, the operands are fetched for the instruction. In a very naive pipeline implementation, the operands for read  will only be visible after the write instruction has written back its changes to the internal registers (so the last stage).

To prevent such long stalls, a CPU can apply tricks like forwarding the store to the load as soon as the value is determined instead of needing to wait for the write to the registers.

Check out the following for a more detailed answer:
https://youtu.be/EL8uqzSsg_Q?t=433

Answer (score 0):

All cpu pipelines are multi-cycle. In the MIPS five-stage pipeline
registers are read in the second stage called ID (instruction
decode/register fetch). And instructions usually stall as late as
possible. For example in

```
daddi   r1, r2, r3
daddi   r4, r5, r1
```

the second instruction will stall for three cycles at ID because it
can't proceed until the first instruction has written to `r1` which
happens in the pipeline's fifth stage.